# Trying to Buy an Item from an External Website with Post Request

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to buy an item from an [external website](https://download.prosoundeffects.com/) using their private API and the python requests module. The problem is that for the request form data it wants the cart items which basically I construct manually to be the exact same as the cart would make them, they are exactly the same as far as I can tell. When I post the request I get an error from the server saying that it isn't getting any cart items.

I've tried matching the headers encoding(the original request uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded), using requests JSON kwarg instead of data, and also adding items to the cart manually, fetching them, and then sending those.  I'm thinking it may be that I need to encode them first, but I have no clue to what.

Here's some code

```py
login_data = {'email': 'email', 'password': 'password123'}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36',
           'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

s = requests.Session()
login_response = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)  # login
data_charge = {'cartItems':[cartItems], # This is a list of dicts
               'key': 'licensing', 
               'nonce': credit_card_token,  # I have to get the card token which works fine
               'cardholder': 'John Smith'}
purchase_response = s.post(url_charge, data=data_charge, headers=headers)
```

The purchase_response.json() content returns "content":[{"error":"No cart items sent."}].
It should respond with order numbers and all the items that were purchased.

Let me know if I'm missing any important details.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
purchase_response = s.post(url_charge, data=data_charge, headers=headers)
```

With:

```
purchase_response = s.post(url_charge, json=data_charge, headers=headers)
```

hope this helps